# Why can I boot Xubuntu 12.04 from usb on one computer but not the other?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, live-usb

When I boot Xubuntu from a flash drive on the old Dell computer mentioned in the about me screen it works fine, but when I try to boot it on another computer (the computer I'm typing this text on) it says "boot errror" and I have to manually shut it down. When I take out the flash drive, it boots windows xp fine. Please help! By the way, I haven't tried booting any other OSes from usb on this computer.

Comment: I've never had a computer refuse to run Ubuntu **except for one with an unsupported video card.** That's where I'd start looking. If you could post the video in this machine, or even the manufacturer and model, there are lots of people who can help you.

Comment: The computer that would run it is the one in the description of my profile and the one that wouldn't run it is a Dell Inspiron 530 with a 2.4 GHz Intel core 2 quad, 3 GB of RAM, and windows xp

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't my idea, but here's what I've found via Google:

[Dell Inspiron 530 and 545 Ubuntu 13.04 Live DVD won't Run](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139574)

Having spent all morning solving this problem, I thought I'd share the solution in case it helps someone else out there...

Problem:
Inspiron 530 and 545 PCs won't boot Ubuntu 13.04 live DVD. Boot error message shows. DVD works fine on other PCs

Attempted Solution:
Use USB image. USB stick works on other PCs, not on the Dells

Actual Solution:

1) Burn plop boatloader onto a CD http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html

2) Make USB image of 13.04

3) Run plop from CD

4) Choose USB and boot into 13.04